# Unable to change in stock text for products in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, product, stock

This is quite a weird one...
At some point previously, we had changed the default 'In Stock' text to 'Available to order' on products in Magento.

Default:-
    Availability: In Stock

New:-
    Availability: Available to order

The thing is, we can't find where or how this is being overridden...

In the below file, the default stock messages In Stock and Out of Stock still remain. If I display template hints with block names on the front end, the block points to this file. If I change the text 'In Stock' in this file, it does change the text 'Available to order' on the front end.

```
/app/design/frontend/*/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

There are no CSS / JS text replaces for this and there are no language files edited to change the text 'In Stock' to 'Available to order'.

In fact, I have done a site search on the entire contents of the /app directory on the server and there is no results found for 'Available to order' in any file.

All cache has been cleared (including cache storage), and full reindex has been performed.

All I'm trying to achieve, is to change it back to 'In Stock' from 'Available to order' but as per the template file, it is already set to 'In Stock'.

Fast running out of ideas on this one...

Comment: Have you ever change stock message with translate inline function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever change stock message with translate inline function? I think message was changed with translate inline function, check in your db entry to find this message.

Check your **core_translate** table or either change it with translate inline function.

Comment: Wow, the only thing I have in this table is exactly where the problem lies... (string) Mage_Catalog::In stock (translate) Available to order. Thank you so much. The fact that this is within the core_translate table, does this mean that it was definitely translated inline? Thanks.

Comment: Yes if this string is in core_translate table then it was definitely translated inline or other possibility is that translate csv was change

Comment: That table in the database must have been the only place I didn't look. Thanks again, great help! :)